# How to generate letter in all possible combinations with specific length limit?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to generate letter in all possible combinations with specific length limit? in javascript

```
// return [aaaa, bbbb]

function allPossibleCombinations(inputArray, outputEachStrLength) {
  var inputArrayLength = inputArray.length;
  for (i = 0; i < inputArrayLength; i++) {

  }
}

var inputArray = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z];
var outputEachStrLength = 4;
allPossibleCombinations(inputArray, outputEachStrLength)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0jqkpLmv/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a recursive method:

```
function allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr) {
    if(curstr.length == length) return [ curstr ];
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        ret.push.apply(ret, allPossibleCombinations(input, length, curstr + input[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}

var input = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
console.log(allPossibleCombinations(input, 3, ''));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, what is `curstr`?

Comment: The `curstr` is the current letter combination being generated. Each time the function is called, it will loop through the input and append each letter to it. If the `curstr` is long enough, then it will be returned.

Comment: I get it!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: I wanted to use this function with an input array of 36 characters to calculate all strings with a fixed length of 5 characters but it fails with: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I guess I put too much load on it. :D

Comment: @DavidFang Is there a quick way to have this "export" on single lines so I can easily copy and paste into excel?